# How can I change the default due date for emails I flag for follow-up?

Tags: samsung, email, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Lollipop.  In the stock "Email" app, I have the ability to flag messages for follow-up but for some reason when I press the flag icon, it sets the due date for the follow-up to "next week".

I want to change the default date for follow-up to "today".  Microsoft Outlook lets me define a new default date but I don't see a similar configurable option in Android.  Is this possible?  If so, how can I change this?

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this, I am looking for the same solution. Thanks

Comment: @John I ended up switching mail apps. I bought one called "nine". While it's expensive (10 bucks), it's worth every penny and offers full customizability on the followup toggle.  There's a free trial for it. Give it a whirl